# What is the purpose of a braze-on on the underside of seat stay?

Tags: braze-on

I have a Jamis Citizen 2 Step through (2013 or 14 maybe) which has a braze-on on the underside of the seat stay near the brake studs.  Just one braze on each side.  I'm curious as to what the intent is and what opportunities they enable.  I already mounted rack and fenders so I'm not talking about the brazes near the seat tube.  In the photo behind the link look closely and see the braze-on just on the inside of the back wheel.

Here is the bike:

http://www.myjamis.com/SSP%20Applications/JamisBikes/MyJamis/consumer/bike.html?year=2014&model=Citizen%202%20Femme&cat_grp=fem_11

Photo:

http://www.myjamis.com/SSP%20Applications/JamisBikes/MyJamis/consumer/images/fancy/14_citizen2step-thru_bl.jpg

Zoomed in photo highlighting the specific braze-on:
[image]

Comment: Since that is a "comfort bike", I would initially suspect the braze-ons are to fit something like a child seat, but then there would be eyelets on the rear dropout.  If it were only on the drive side, I'd suspect it's for a chain shield, but you're ambiguous as to whether there are two or only one.  Or the wheel lock theory is a good one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I believe those are for a **frame-mounted wheel lock**. These are locks that you mount to the frame in roughly that location that immobilize the rear wheel when locked. Typically they mount via the brake braze-ons or their own straps, but that location looks about right for a direct mount

An example of a fitted lock can be seen in this image:

[image: AXA lock on Jamis]

This type of lock is convenient, but not especially secure, since a thief can always just pick up the bike and carry it off. Some do include a way to plug in a cable or chain in order to lock the bike up to something else, but those aren't especially secure, either.

Comment: I had that idea myself after looking at this photo.

Comment: AXA Defenders have plug-in chains as well as plug-in cables available, for what it's worth.

Comment: Confirmed per email from Jamis

Answer (score -1):

I believe those are for frame-mount rear racks. While some can attach to the seat post, others can attach to the frame. The link shows an example:

http://www.bikebagshop.com/salsa-alternator-rear-rack-p-3187.html

Comment: I'm not certain I'm following you here on this.  The link and product page only show the standard mountings for a frame mounted rack.  I'll try to add some to my question to see if we are on the same page.

Comment: Those usually mount to the braze-ons on the outside of the seat stays. This question is about a more unusual braze-on on the underside of the seat stays.

Comment: The braze-ons that @freiheit are talking about and that those racks attach to are actually visible in the picture in the OP's post.

Comment: Correct, I keep forgetting to take a photo of them when I'm at home.